# Android Adapters

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have one adapter for two different listviews, the code show no error but I don't understand why the second listview does'nt show. I have two listviews in two different activity. I don't know my problem here so can you please tell me what should I do? I mean is there something I need to rename or add inside my adapters?

**This is My first adapter**
[image]

> This code works just fine

```
public class PdfAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pdf>
{
    Activity activity;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Pdf> data=new ArrayList<Pdf>();
    Pdf pdf;

    public PdfAdapter(Activity activity, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Pdf> data) {
        super(activity, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PdfHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);
            holder = new PdfHolder();
            holder.textViewName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            holder.textViewUrl = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewUrl);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder= (PdfHolder) row.getTag();

        }

        pdf = data.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(pdf.getName());
        holder.textViewUrl.setText(pdf.getUrl());
        return row;
    }


    class PdfHolder
    {
        TextView textViewName,textViewUrl;
    }
```

[image]

> Here is my problem, and I wonder what I need to do so that the pdfs would show

Comment: Why do you need 2 adapters with te same code? Maybe the problem is in the way you're creating the adapters and setting in the activity, paste the code here.

Comment: Did you check the data list for size . An dseems like you do not even need Two adapters cause both are almost same.

Comment: @miibpa I would like to use it for two different activities, the first one works and the other is not.

Comment: @ADM sir I edited my post now, I only have one adapter for two activities, one works well and the other activity only shows up successfully fetched but it doesn't show a list

Comment: Log getCount of Adapter if its returning the size over Zero then there must be some layout issue with your list .

Comment: But you can use the same adapter in both Activities, try what @ADM said, check if you're filling the adapter with an array with more than 0 elements

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, as I checked my code last night I just misspelled on my php code. I fixed it :))